# Ubuntu Phone - How can I program app running, when device screen is turned off?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, phone, desktop-background

How can I program my mobile application to be still running in the background, after the user turned off the screen?

I'm developing the application in [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html).

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1462489

Comment: No. I want to run a pedometer. The mobile phone is in my pant pocket and it needs to be screen off. It also needs to run in the background, when an another application is present.

Comment: Well, the problem isn't when I turn off the screen, I discovered. It's the problem when I switch between applications.

Comment: Update: The problem is, when I switch to another app and turn the screen off of my phone. Otherwise it works.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu's app lifecycle policy prevents any app from running in the background. Only the currently active app on the screen is allowed to use the devices resources, any app open in the background is suspended.

Ted Gould recently did a talk on the lifecycle policy https://youtu.be/v5iY2NgaBeY which explains all this nicely

Comment: its not totally true music app use background running its pid backgrounded

Comment: @ouccema the music app does get suspended but it queues a playlist with media-hub which is a system service and media-hub will play that playlist whether the musicapp is backgrounded/suspended or is the focused application.